# Inheritance: Evaluating In Derived Class's Scope?

Tags: java, c++, oop, design-patterns, d

Is there a design pattern in any mainstream language for a derived class to inherit code from a base class **and evaluate that code in the derived class's scope?**  For example (using pseudo-C++ syntax):

```
class Base {
    // (How) can this be modified to be evaluated 
    // in the derived class's scope so that it
    // prints the size of the derived class?
    void printSize() {
        cout << sizeof(*this) << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    void* dummy;
};

int main() {
    Base base;
    Derived derived;
    base.printSize();  
    derived.printSize();  // Should be > base.printSize().
    return 0;
}
```

I realize this can be done with macros, but that requires the macro to be explicitly instantiated in the derived class's scope.

**EDIT:**    To clarify, the whole point of this post is that I don't want to manually re-implement `printSize()` or anything similar in every derived class.  I'm looking for a clever pattern to make the compiler/interpreter (I'm interested in knowing whether any language has a solution for this even though I used C++ in my example) do this for me.

**EDIT # 2:**  I guess this is pretty easy in dynamic languages.  I'm more interested in solutions for statically typed languages, mostly C++, Java and D.

**EDIT # 3:** The pattern should work on the runtime type, not the compile time type.  Therefore, D's template this parameters are not a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by evaluate? in the case you gave it looks like normal inheritance to me

Comment: printSize() will always print the size of the base class because it's compiled once in the scope of Base.  I want it to print the size of the derived class if it's called on an instance of Derived.

Comment: This will only apply to the c++ language.  With java, and proper java syntax of course, this would automatically be considered virtual and would print the derived classes size

Comment: Note that `printSize()` returns `void`, so you probably don't want to `cout <<` it; you probably intend to just call `printSize()` by itself.

Comment: @Adam:  Right.  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

If by "mainstream", you include mainstream scripting languages such as Perl or Python, then yes.  Perl methods are generally "evaluated" in the most-derived scope, since a Perl "object" is generally a hash-map and all variables from all levels of the inheritance tree are in the same "scope" (that is, keys into the same hash-map).  Something similar happens for Python classes, although (IIRC) Python has a way of creating a symbol that will be mangled so that it will be distinct based on the class the code is written in.  Of course, neither of these languages has a "sizeof" concept per se, so your particular example wouldn't be particularly relevant.

In C++, the concept of deciding the current class for a member function based on the type it's called through like your example doesn't (as far as I know) really work.  However, you might be able to get close to what you're describing using templates.  For example, something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void printSize( T &t ) {
    cout << sizeof(t) << endl;
}
int main() {
    Base base;
    Derived derived;
    printSize(base);
    printSize(derived);
}
```

(Side note: In C++, since your `Base` is empty, there's actually no guarantee that `sizeof(Base)` > `sizeof(Derived)` --- the empty base optimization may be employed such that a normal `Base` is (perhaps) the size of a pointer, but the `Base` part of a `Derived` is actually empty.  Most platforms probably allocate 1 byte to such empty classes, and pointers are usually bigger than that, but it's not specified.)

Answer (score 2):

D comes for the rescue. [Template mixins](http://dlang.org/template-mixin.html) are exactly the tool intended for being evaluated in target context and you don't need any special type hierarchy (you can still add one if you want of course):

http://dpaste.1azy.net/eec411e8

```
mixin template SizePrinter()
{
    static void printSize()
    {
        import std.stdio;
        writeln(__traits(classInstanceSize, typeof(this)));
    }
}

class Tested1
{
    int[64] dummy;
    mixin SizePrinter;
}

class Tested2
{
    int[16] dummy;
    mixin SizePrinter;
}

void main()
{
    Tested1.printSize();
    Tested2.printSize();
}
```

Application output:

```
272
80
```

Comment: I was aware of template mixins in D.  It's a better solution than C++ has to offer, but it still requires something explicit to be done in the derived classes, which can be annoying even if it's a one-liner.

Comment: Ah, dsimcha, sorry, I have not noticed it was asked by someone from D community. Are you fine with RTTI approach?

Comment: RTTI would solve the problem for the specific case of wanting the size of the class, but it's not a general solution.

Comment: @dsimcha Well, you absolutely need some kind of run time reflection because Base class can't possibly control or know who inherits from it. If you only care about limited set of modules, you can iterate all classes in those, find those who have target Base and use typeid to identify current one. If you want this to work across dynamically loaded library boundaries, some form of run time type registration needs to be implemented and there is no way to avoid it.

Comment: But I still question if it wise to spend that much efforts to avoid explicitly using mixin statement (and explicitly use inheritance instead) for something that D type system is designed to actually prevent,

Answer (score 1):

In C++, I think the closer you'll get to that is the *Curiously Recurring Template Pattern* (CRTP) but it has serious limitations:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
    void printSize() {
        std::cout << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
    }
    void doSomething() {
        T::member_variable = 3;
        T::doSomethingElse();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
    int member_variable;
    void doSomethingElse() { ... }
};
```

You could also use virtual methods but they require you to reimplement the method in each and every derived class, so I guess this is not what you want.

To really achieve what you have in mind, you'll probably need a dynamic language (eg. Python). No guarantees though, this is such an unusual "feature request" and I don't know dynamic languages very well...

Answer (score 1):

There is a better solution in D that uses [Template This Parameter](http://dlang.org/template.html#TemplateThisParameter).

Code: http://dpaste.1azy.net/78810a79

```
import std.stdio;

class Base {
  int[64] dummy1;
  final static size_t getSize(this T)() {
    return __traits(classInstanceSize, T);
  }
}

class Derived : Base {
  int[16] dummy2;
}

void main() {
  writeln(Base.getSize());    // prints: 272
  writeln(Derived.getSize()); // prints: 336
}
```

Edit: Ops, this will only work for the static type. Not the solution to your problem.